# Hibernate Template with Transactions

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring, rollback

I have a java/spring webapp which uses HibernateTemplate and I was wondering if it was possible to use SQL transactions with hibernate template.

For example, suppose that I have the following dao code:

```
getHibernateTemplate().save(newObject);
getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(someObject);
getHibernateTemplate().delete(oldObject);
```

Suppose that I want either all three statements to succeed or all three to fail. Is there any way to accomplish this with hibernate template? Can I use a try/catch block? If so, what would I put in the catch block to rollback the hibernate template statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Spring to manage your transactions (I see it as one of your tags).

The basic idea is that you group a bunch of persistence operations, that you want to all participate in one transaction, in one method (in a service class), and you [configure Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) to make that service method transactional.

One relatively easy way to do it is to configure spring to make all service methods transactional, but you are not constrained to this -- you can make it as easy or complicated as you want.

Comment: Could you at least link to an example or some relevant documentation? I understand the general idea is to use a transaction, but I see nothing in the HibernateTemplate API which permits this.

Comment: There is a link in the second paragraph at the text 'configure Spring'.  You probably want declarative transaction management within that document.

Comment: You can use org.springframework.orm.hibernate.HibernateTransactionManager implementation. You have to set the sessionFactory property only. Use this line in the appcontext to manage transactions with annotations: <tx:annotation-driven/>

Answer (score 2):

As @hvgotcodes pointed out, transactions are managed on the Service layer rather than in a persistence layer. This is due to the meaning of things to be transactional => which most of the time is defined by the business, hence service/domain layer.

Here is an example of how to transact your service via Spring AOP XML configuration:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="moneyMakingBusinessServiceMethods"
                  expression="execution(* org.gitpod.startup.service.MoneyMakingBusinessService.*(..))"/>

    <aop:advisor advice-ref="moneyMakingAdvice"
                 pointcut-ref="moneyMakingBusinessServiceMethods"/>
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="moneyMakingAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="makeMoney" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="withdrawMoney" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true"/>            
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="SUPPORTS" read-only="true"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

This approach is good, because you do not need to pollute your services with `@Transactional`, `@SomethingElse` annotations, and all your TX management/configuration is defined in a single place [ this is my personal belief ].

This service will take a Dao/Repository or two, and will delegate all the persistence workings to it:

```
public class CleverMoneyMakingBusinessService implements MoneyMakingBusinessService {

    private MoneyRepository moneyRepository;

    public void makeMoney( MoneyRoll money )  {
        moneyRepository.make( money );
    }

    public MoneyRoll withdrawMoney( Long moneyRollId ) {
        return moneyRepository.find( moneyRollId );
    }

    public void setMoneyRepository( MoneyRepository moneyRepository ) {
        this.moneyRepository = moneyRepository;
    }
}
```

Whereas Repository/DAO may look like this (note that it does not use `HibernateTemplate`, since `@Repository` does all the Exception translations, and Hibernate `SessionFactory` can and *should* be used directly):

```
@Repository
public class HibernateMoneyRepository implements MoneyRepository {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public MoneyRoll find( Long rollId ) {

        MoneyRoll moneyRoll = null;

        Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery("find.moneyroll.by.id");
        query.setParameter( "id", rollId );

        List<MoneyRoll> moneyList = query.list();

        if ( moneyList.size() != 0 ) {
            moneyRoll = ( MoneyRoll )query.list().get( 0 );
        }

        return moneyRoll;
    }

    public void make( MoneyRoll moneyRoll ) {
        getSession().save( moneyRoll );
    }

    public void takeOut( MoneyRoll moneyRoll ) {
        getSession().delete( moneyRoll );
    }

    public void update(MoneyRoll money) {

        Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery("update.moneyroll");
        query.setParameter( "id", money.getId() );
        query.setParameter( "amount", money.getAmount() );
        query.setParameter( "currency", money.getCurrency() );

        query.executeUpdate();
    }

    private Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }   
}
```

Take a look at the [money making project](https://github.com/tolitius/money-making-project) that I put together as an example, to see how it all comes together and executes.